# Colocar um Array num cookie em PHP

Tags: php, array, session, cookies

Tenho uma query que me retorna os acessos do usuário que acabou de logar. Preciso transformar elas em um array e armazenar em uma sessão e em um cookie. Segue código:

```
//ARMAZENA AS PERMISSOES DO PERFIL DO USUARIO
if($sql_permissoes->rowCount() > 0){
    $permissao_visualizacao = array();
    $permissao_alteracao        = array();
    foreach ($sql_permissoes as $sql_permissoes_row) {
        $permissao_visualizacao[]   = $sql_permissoes_row["url_localizacao"];
        $permissao_alteracao[]      = $sql_permissoes_row["permite_alteracao"];
    }
}

$_SESSION["ged.permissao.visualizacao"] = $permissao_visualizacao;
$_SESSION["ged.permissao.alteracao"]    = $permissao_alteracao;
setcookie("ged.permissao.visualizacao", $permissao_visualizacao, mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+5, date("Y")) );
setcookie("ged.permissao.alteracao", $permissao_alteracao, mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+5, date("Y")) );
```

Porém nas linhas do setcookie eu recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
Warning: setcookie() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given.
```

Qual o método mais recomendado de fazer essa operação?

Comment: Até pode funcionar, mas lembre-se os navegadores podem ter limitação no tamanho do armazenamento, talvez o melhor seja armazenar nas sessões do servidor e usar o cookie apenas para indentificar qual sessão é de quem (o próprio `session_*` já faz isto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso o nome do seu cookie tiver algum **ponto**, ao utilizar o `setcookie`, ele **será transformado em underline**.

No meu exemplo, como estava armazenando o cookie `ged.permissao.visualizacao`, recuperei ele como `ged_permissao_visualizacao` e deu certo.

http://harrybailey.com/2009/04/dots-arent-allowed-in-php-cookie-names/

Valeu **@GeBender** pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa boa é serializar o array, ou seja, transformar em uma string:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

```
setcookie("ged.permissao.visualizacao", serialize($permissao_visualizacao), mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+5, date("Y")) );
setcookie("ged.permissao.alteracao", serialize($permissao_alteracao), mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+5, date("Y")) );
```

Para ler o cookie você deve usar o unserialize:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

```
$permissao_visualizacao = unserialize($_COOKIE['ged_permissao_visualizacao']);
$permissao_alteracao = unserialize($_COOKIE['ged_permissao_visualizacao']);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Utilizando o `serialize` parou de dar erro no `setcookie`, porém ao tentar recuperar ele com o `unserialize` o erro aparece: `Notice: Undefined index: ged.permissao.visualizacao`. Vale lembrar que fiz o teste logo após o cookie ser criado e também após o redirecionamento da página, ambos com o mesmo retorno.

Comment: @DirtyOldMan, fiz o teste aqui e não sei o motivo, mas o setcookie troca os pontos por underscore, dê um `var_dump($_COOKIE)` e veja como ficou salvo seu cookie. resposta editada.

Answer (score 0):

Como o erro sugere, dados de cookies devem estar no formato string. Mais importante, você não deve armazenar dados reais em um cookie, porque o usuário pode editá-los.

```
$permissao_visualizacao = unserialize($_COOKIE['ged.permissao.visualizacao']);
```

session_start () deve ser chamado antes de qualquer coisa é a saída em cada página.

caso o erro persista tente utilizar um terceiro parâmetro no set cookie `setcookie('email', $first_email, time()+60*60*24*100);`